# SQL Code to get results when there are no records in a table

Tags: sql, subquery, left-join, inner-join

There are 4 tables (user, user options, option type 1, and option type 2).  The user table is not directly involved here but mentioned for completeness. Here are the table columns for each of the involved tables.

```
User Options:
    UserID,
    Option1ID,
    Option2ID,

Option1:
    Option1ID,
    Option1Description

Option2:
    Option2ID,
    Option2Description
```

All the values for Option1 can be combined with all the values for Option2 hence if there a 'x' number of Option1 values and 'y' number of Option2 values then the resultant number of option combinations is 'x' * 'y'.  I want to write a query such that it will always result in 'x' * 'y' rows for a given UserID even if there is no record for a particular combination of Option1ID and Option2ID for that user in the UserOptions table.  Additionally there should be a column that indicates if the particular combination of Option1 and Option2 exists in the UserOptions table.

```
Option1
Option1ID   Option1Description
----------------------------------
1           1_Description1
2           1_Description2


Options2
Option2ID   Option2Description
----------------------------------
1           2_Description1
2           2_Description2


UserOptions
UserID  Option1ID   Option2ID
---------------------------------
1       1           2
1       2           2


Result
UserID  Option1ID   Option2ID   Exists
----------------------------------------------
1       1           1           0
1       1           2           1
1       2           1           0
1       2           2           1
```

Given the above what would the SQL query be?  In addition note that UserID = 2 does not exist in the UsersOptions table.  In this case the query should still return 4 records where the UserID column will always be 2, the OptionID columns will be the same, and the Exists column will always be 0.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: @philipxy please note that I already marked the response by GMB as an acceptable answer before your comment.

Comment: That doesn't matter to my comment. Research the site goals & protocols. The purpose of the site is not getting answers for askers. [help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: I'm confused, can clear things up for me. You said that I didn't include enough detail even though someone seemed to have enough information to answer the query without asking for additional details. I would be interested in @GMB assessment whether the question included enough information or required more details. Then you say "The purpose of this site is not getting answers for [sic]askers" yet the site uses a button "Ask Question" and logically (at least in my mind) from questions come answers. It seems to me that in fact that is exactly what the site is about getting answers for questions.

Comment: It seems you still haven't educated yourself about the site. PS Your `@` will not have notified GMB of its comment because they are not a commeter on this post. (You can leave a comment on their answer.) (`@` not needed.) See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use `@x` to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter `x` re a comment. (Posters & followers aways get notified.) PS GMB constantly answers questions that are obvious duplicates that should instead be closed. PS Consider posting (post-research) at [meta].

Comment: @tdinpsp philpxy isn't a moderator ( neither am I btw ;) ) and definitely not a "troll". They are simply trying to explain to you why your question might be closed. On SO we expect you to show us some code or what you have worked on. Even though GMB could answer you question, it is still advisable to avoid asking questions that don't have a line of code to show. Also please avoid using terms like "troll" because they go agaist the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: My perspective is different.  I don't mind as much if people have not entered all the information that my be needed to answer a question.  Often they don't even know what is relevant and what is not.  Some people put too much others not enough.  If I can answer, I answer, if I need more I ask, if there's too much I might just move on.  But I won't tell people what they should or should not do.

Comment: FYI Only followers got notification of your last comment, no @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cross join` the users table with the two options tables to generate all possible combinations, then search for a match in bridge table `useroptions` with a `left join`:

```
select u.userid, o1.option1id, o2.option2id, 
    case when uo.userid is null then 0 else 1 end as uo_exists
from users u
cross join option1 o1
cross join option2 o2
left join useroptions uo 
    on  uo.userid = u.id
    and uo.option1id = o1.option1id
    and uo.option2id = o1.option2id
```

You could also use `exists` instead of a `left join`:

```
select u.userid, o1.option1id, o2.option2id, 
    case when exists (
        select 1 
        from useroptions uo 
        where  uo.userid = u.id and uo.option1id = o1.option1id and uo.option2id = o1.option2iduo.userid
    ) then 1 else 0 end as uo_exists
from users u
cross join option1 o1
cross join option2 o2
```

Comment: Is there one method that is more efficient than the other?

Comment: @tdinpsp: hard to tell for sure, you would probably need to assess that against your actual dataset. I would try the correlated subquery first, with an index on useroptions`(userid, option1id, option2id)`.